# How to call worksheet functions in VBA outlook?

Tags: excel, vba, string, outlook, substitution

I am trying to call a method available in Excel VBA inside of Outlook's VBA.  I need to remove spaces from a string in a clean way (for easy maintenance), so I figured it would be easy to use the "Substitute" method that is available in Excel.  Since Outlook isn't able to use the command "Application.WorksheetFunction.Substitute(...)," how do I call the Substitute method?

pseudo code:

```
dim string1 as String, string2 as String
string1 = "hello world"
string2 = Substitute(string1, " ", "")

>> string2 = "helloworld"
```

Comment: Try using [`Replace`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vba/vba_replace_function.htm)

Comment: It's important to recognize that there are worksheet functions and vba functions and the two are not the same. It's like two different programming languages. Excel is nice in that it allows you to tap into its worksheet function, which often don't have a similar function in VBA, but they should be a last-resort.

Comment: Try doing some research before posting on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing

```
string2 = Replace(string1, " ", "")
```